# Counting Like Circular Linked List

Tags: algorithm, math

I would like to count down with in a limit but in circular manner.

Let us say The limit is 12 and the current iteration is 10 then I would like to the result as 10 - 2 = 8
similar way if the current iteration is 0 the I should have result as follows 0 - 2 = 11 not -2.

The main think I would like to have this as an algorithm / formula.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a typo? `10 - 2 = 9`

Answer (score 4):

Use modolus operator and Zn [group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_%28mathematics%29):

```
(i < 0 ? n + i : i) % n
```

Where `n` is the number - 12 in your example, and `i` is the iteration number.

(assuming `-n <= i`, otherwise you might want to subtract `k*n - i` for some natural `k` to make sure the result is positive. If you do the above step iteratively, this should not be an issue.)

---

As a side note, in pure mathematical concept `-i == n-i` in the Zn group, but most programming languages I am aware of does not do this calculation, and after modolus calculation the sign of the left operand remains the same.

For this we first check the sign, and make sure it is positive.